# Completely change the identity of the project

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

I was going to use some ready third-party written project whose architecture i did like. By the time i am going to change the most of its code. Could someone provide what exactly should i change to completely renew the identity of this project? 
I guess the following needs to be changed.

- "Display name" in Build Settings
- "Bundle identifier" in Build Settings
- "Version" in Build Settings
- "Build" in Build Settings
- "Name" in "Identity and Type"
- "Target name" (then what`s the better place to change it?)
- Targets in the podfile

Could you please correct the list if something was missed? Should i go to info.plist or is some other place is better?

Comment: Change only `Bundle identifier` should be enough, but if the functionalities and UI is similar to some app in store, maybe will get rejected anyway

Comment: I am going to almost completely change the project code. It`s going to be the new one. Just did like the architecture. And it seems that working on the ready one is easier than creating the new one at the moment.

Comment: Change bundle id is enough, since each appstore app must have unique bundle id, display name doesnt matter

Comment: Thanks for collaboration.

Comment: @Tj3n now a days duplicate name also not allow.

Comment: Actually i was not only going to change everything in purpose of applying the project to the app store but also in purpose of making it "look" cleaner. Would not prefer to see one name of a project in one place and another in the other place.

Answer (score 1):

1. Xcode
2. left side (project navigator)
3. select the main project
4. press ENTER
5. rename it in whatever you need
6. press ENTER again

Xcode should be present a window asking you what do you actually want rename.

Comment: Thanks! I have already did. But the "Bundle Identifier"(in the "General" section) , "Display Name", "Version", "Build", "Team" also needed to be changed, same for one more target(did`t mention it in question) and "Organization" in the "Project document" section as well. Also i needed to deintegrate Cocoa Pods using the https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate and run "pod install" again in the terminal.